# Finding the volume using triple integration.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

We need to find the volume of a solid $D$ which is bounded by the paraboloid $z = 1-4(x^{2} + y^{2} )$ and the $xy$ plane.

I made use of the polar co-ordinates :

Taking $x = rcos\theta$ and $y= r sin\theta$  we get the following integral :

$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_0^{1-4r^{2}}rdzdrd\theta $ ,

which gives the value $ \dfrac{\pi}{8}$ , but the solution says $ \dfrac{7\pi}{2}$ ,

I have already checked the calculations ,

Am I interpreting the problem incorrectly ? Can anyone tell ?

Comment: I'd imagine you want to use cylindrical coordinates for this problem.

Comment: I've graphed the surface and I think your bounds of integration are correct. Since you're taking the volume of the shape, 1 is going to be your integrand. Your value for your Jacobian is correct, so I really don't see anything wrong with your setup. Are you absolutely sure that the answer is $\frac{7\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Yes , it says $\dfrac{7 \pi}{2}$ . I've already checked that.. But atleast the approach is correct.. Thanks for the reply .. @Simon